# Como volver a ejecutar el ngOnInit de un componente desde un service?

Tags: angular, angular10

Tengo un componente header donde tengo un botón de login que se muestran si no ha iniciado sesión el usuario. Al hacer clic cambia la vista, inicia sesión y cambia de vista pero al no recargarse ese componente no detecta si ha iniciado sesión.

Componente header html:

```
<div *ngIf="(role == '')" class="d-inline-flex">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Componente header ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const user = this.service.getUser();
}
```

Quería ejecutar el ngOnInit desde el service que guarda el usuario.

Comment: Podrias crear un metodo con todo lo que tiene el ngOnInit y lo ejecutas en el ngOnInit y luego lo ejecutas donde quieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el servicio se puede tener una variable de tipo `Subject` que emita el estado de la sesión.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SesionService {

  private estadoSesion : Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  getEstadoSesion(){
    return this.estadoSesion;
  }

  iniciarSesion(){

   // lógica para iniciar sesión

    // al iniciar sesión emitir un resultado para que los clientes
    // sepan que hay sesión iniciada
    this.estadoSesion.next(true);
  }

}
```

Y el componente puede suscribirse a esa variable, así cuando se inicie sesión el botón se ocultará.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { SesionService } from "./sesion.service";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <button *ngIf="!sesionIniciada" (click)="iniciarSesion()">
      Iniciar sesión
    </button>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {

  sesionIniciada: boolean = false;

  constructor(private sesion: SesionService) {

    this.sesion.getEstadoSesion().subscribe(estado => {
      this.sesionIniciada = estado;
    });
    
  }

  iniciarSesion() {
    this.sesion.iniciarSesion();
  }
}
```

[Ejemplo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9zjfd5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)